# Determine the solution set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of the homogeneous linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$2x + 4y + z = 0$

$x + y + 2z = 0$

$x + 3y − z = 0$

Show that the solution set $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Given the subspace

$U = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x-y+z=0\} $,

determine a system of generators for the subspace $S \cap U $.

I'm having trouble to prove that the solution of the system is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of a vector space, you should make clear to yourself that the following steps show that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

1) Show that $(0,0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a solution by evaluation the left sites of the equations.

2) Let $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2)\in S$, which means that these values satisfy all equations. Now show that also

$(x_1, y_1, z_1) + (x_2, y_2, z_2) = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2)$

and

$\alpha \cdot (x_1, y_1, z_1) = (\alpha \cdot x_1, \alpha \cdot y_1, \alpha \cdot z_1)$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

are solutions.

Comment: That makes sense. So, the solution of the system itself is not needed to prove that S is a subspace, right? This is what was making me confused at first. Thank you for your solution!

Comment: Thats correct, you don't need to find a basis of $S$ to show the closure of $S$ under vector space operations. Please flag it as the answer if this is what you were asking for.

Comment: All right! Also, thanks for your feedback on formatting

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Note that $0$ in $S$.

Also, suppose $Ax_1=0$ and $Ax_2=0$, verify that $A(x_1+x_2) =0$. (closure under addition)

Suppose $Ax_1=0$, show that $A(kx_1)=0$. (closure under scalar multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$-2y+3z=0$$
multiplying the first by $-2$ and adding to the third we obtain
$$-2y+3z=0$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Sum the second line to the third then subtract the third to the first, then multiply the second line by two and subtract it to the third $\begin{bmatrix}2&4&1&0\\1&1&2&0\\1&3&-1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&4&1&0\\1&1&2&0\\2&4&1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\1&1&2&0\\2&4&1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\1&1&2&0\\0&2&-3&0\end{bmatrix}$

We get a simpler system:

$x+y+2z=0\\2y-3z=0\implies x+y+2z=0\\y=\frac{3}{2}z\implies x=-\frac{7}{2}\\y=\frac{3}{2}z$

Now take $z=1$, we get the following basis $(-\frac{7}{2},\frac{3}{2},1)$, that generates the space of solutions of the system and it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now you can check if the basis generates a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, if the sum of two vectors generated by the basis is a solution and if a vector multiplied by a scalar is a solution of the given system. The later is obvious, you can manipulate the value of $z$, which proves the assertion.